# Install debian 8 on a LVM Volume with Type RAID1 GRUB2 cant find volume group

Tags: linux, debian, lvm, boot, grub2

**Hello Community!**

I tried the whole day long to setup up an LVM type Raid1
Volume on Debian 8.5, but the Server is not be able to 
boot from it.

First of all here is the error i get from GRUB2:

[GRUB2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/krroO.png)

[lvm lvs & lvm pvs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cvdgg.png)

here are the steps i made, first i boot into grml (a Live-CD/Rescue-System): (factory new /dev/sda & /dev/sdb )

**1 . then i create the partitions on both drives:**

- 512M Primary (Linux raid autodetect)
- 20G Primary 8e (Linux LVM)

**2. now i create the Raid for my /boot and format as ext4**

- mdadm --create /dev/md0 --level=1 --raid-disks=2 /dev/sda1 /dev/sdb1
- mkfs.ext4 /dev/md0

**3. its time for the volume group**

`pvcreate /dev/sda2
pvcreate /dev/sdb2
vgcreate vg0 /dev/sda2 /dev/sdb2`

**4. we come to the volumes and format them**

`lvcreate -n root -L 20G vg0 --type raid1
lvcreate -n swap -L 4G vg0 --type raid1`

`root@grml ~ # lvscan
      ACTIVE            '/dev/vg0/root' [10,00 GiB] inherit
      ACTIVE            '/dev/vg0/swap' [4,00 GiB] inherit`

`mkfs.ext4 /dev/vg0/root mkswap /dev/vg0/swap`

**5. mount the volumes**

`mount /dev/vg0/root /mnt
cd /mnt
mkdir boot
mkdir proc
mkdir dev
mkdir sys
mkdir home
mount /dev/md0 boot/`

6. create fstab

`mkdir etc
cd etc
vi fstab`

```
`proc /proc   proc   defaults 0 0
/dev/md0 /boot   ext4   defaults 0 2
/dev/vg0/root /              ext4   defaults 0 1
/dev/vg0/swap          none      swap  defaults,pri=1 0 0`
```

**7. debootstrap debian jessie**

`debootstrap --arch amd64 jessie /mnt ftp://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/`

**8. mount some essentials**

`mount -t proc none /mnt/proc
mount -o bind /dev /mnt/dev
mount -o bind /sys /mnt/sys`

**9. chroot into the shiny new debian**

`chroot /mnt /bin/bash`

**10. set a new root password**
`passwd`

**11. add contrib & non-free to the sourcelist**

`nano /etc/apt/sources.list`

`deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian jessie main contrib non-free`

**12. install packages**

`apt-get install mdadm openssh-server lvm2 locales ntp vim-nox firmware-realtek`

**13. configure locales**

`dpkg-reconfigure locales tzdata`

**14. install the kernel**

`apt-get install linux-image-amd64`

**15. grub2**
`apt-get install grub2`

*selecting sda & sdb as install devices*

`grub-install --no-floppy /dev/sda
grub-install --no-floppy /dev/sdb
update-grub /dev/md0
update-initramfs -u`

**16. exit and reboot**

`exit
shutdown -r now`

maybe any body can help me, i hope i only forget something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Redhat staff](https://www.redhat.com/archives/linux-lvm/2014-April/msg00017.html):

> *Grub doesn't support LVM RAID1 (it supports only RAID 4/5/6 type IIRC)*.

Debian 8 has some old interior, you could hit the same limitation, I wanted to find some official info about Grub's limitations, unfortunately I've failed.

> ```
> Re: [linux-lvm] GRUB boot problem with lvm mirror type raid1
>
> From: Peter Rajnoha <prajnoha redhat com>
> To: gk180984 interia pl
> Cc: LVM general discussion and development <linux-lvm redhat com>
> Subject: Re: [linux-lvm] GRUB boot problem with lvm mirror type raid1
> Date: Mon, 14 Apr 2014 11:40:36 +0200
> ```
>
> > ```
> > On 04/14/2014 10:42 AM, gk180984 interia pl wrote:
> > Hi
> > I want to ask it is possible boot root file system (via GRUB) from LVM
> > RAID1 volume?
> > I can boot root file system (with /boot) from linera LVM volume and
> > from mirror volume, but when I create raid1 mirror GRUB can't boot from it:
> >
> > lvconvert --type raid1 -m1 gsys/vsys
> >
> > LVM mirror is work:
> > lvconvert -m1 gsys/vsys
> >
> > I have two disk and use only LVM, not other raid software.
> > GRUB have lvm module.
> > ```
>
> ```
> Grub doesn't support LVM RAID1 (it supports only RAID 4/5/6 type IIRC).
>
> However, I don't recommend using /boot on LVM at the moment since
> grub support for LVM is limited and unofficial. There's a plan to add
> official and more robust support though - there are ongoing discussions
> between grub and LVM team...
> ```

Comment: It seams that everybody does, including me. It's way more mature, well documented like anything else.